# All Players SItting Out

Tags: dealer

Is the dealer expected to stop dealing if all players at a table are sitting out?
Does this behavior differ depending on the type of game? MTT / Ring Game / SnG?

Comment: At least two players must be present in order for the dealer to start dealing. I can't see what other options we have here.

Comment: @yazanpro I think that comment qualifies as a (good) answer

Comment: How could you deal to no players even if you wanted to?

Comment: What if a table agreed to all sit out at a MTT? They would be guaranteed to last longer than any other tables still in play.

Comment: If a whole table in a tournament agreed to not sit down that would be player collusion and they could be subject to disqualification.

Comment: I believe with an online tournament the players cannot site out, they are dealt in and the hand is killed when they time out. Same thing in a B&M tournament, only the hand is mucked immediately if the player is not in their seat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have much experience live, so these answers only apply to online poker, but I believe the answer should apply the same either way.

I'm not sure how this works in ring games, I assume that there is no dealing while everyone is sitting out.

Tournaments and SNGs are different. Players can't truly sit out, as they can in a ring game. The deal continues, with blinds and antes being taken from the players, as necessary.

Comment: In a tournament if you deal and take blinds who would win the pot with no one at the table?

Comment: The pot goes to the big blind.

Comment: I guess that makes sense